# install older virtual environment compatible with python 3.7.4?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Is it possible to install an older virtual environment compatible with python 3.7.4? I want to use python 3.7.4, but when I install a virtual environment with the command:

```
python3 -m pip install pipenv
```

it installs the latest virtual environment, but when I go to activate the virtual environment, I get the following error message in my mac terminal:

```
   Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.8, but you are using 3.7.4 (/Users/myHomepage/.local/share/v/t/bin/python).
      $ pipenv --rm and rebuilding the virtual environment may resolve the issue.
      $ pipenv check will surely fail.
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
```

I am using Visual Studio Code. Any ideas? thnx.

Also can some1 tell me how different Python 3.7.4 is to Python 3.8? I'm following along with a tutorial wherein he says it is highly recommended to use Python 3.7.4 and not 3.8, but how different are they? thnx

Comment: I have to use Visual Studio Code as I'm just following a tutorial, which is the reason why I want to use Python 3.7.4 - thnx

Comment: Can you post your pipfile?

Comment: sure thing, here's the pip file: [[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "==2.2"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8" - thnx

Comment: Well, the pipfile explicitly states python_version 3.8 is required. What if you simply change that to 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use pyenv for managing python versions on mac it's easy to use and available in brew

for installing it in terminal just do:

```sh
$ brew update
$ brew install pyenv
```

and if you are using bash

```sh
$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

finally restart your shell and you can install any python version with the currect pip version using pyenv

```sh
pyenv install 3.8.5
pyenv global 3.8.5
```

Comment: wow thnx Akbar30bill, so I can use any version of Python with the current pip version with pyenv, that snds gr8. I forgot to mention I'm also using Django==2.2
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1 and will also be installing node-v12.18.4-thnx

Comment: i installed pyenv using homebrew, but when i try to activate pyenv with the command: pyenv shell 3.8.3, i get the following message: "pyenv: shell integration not enabled. Run `pyenv init' for instructions." So i run pyenv init, and then it says, "# Load pyenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.zshrc:

eval "$(pyenv init -)" - I don't know how to do this, does any1 know how to do this? I am running a mac os High Sierra 10.13.6 -thnx

Comment: Ultimately, I want to use Python 3.7.4, this is why I installed pyenv. I i type pyenv global 3.7.4 into the command line I get pyenv: version `3.7.4' not installed, but i did install python 3.7.4. If I type python -V into the command line, I get Python 3.8.3. How do I install python3.7.4 so pyenv will see it. Also it should b noted,i've been having problems b4 with bash wherein i have to type: PATH=/Users/aleong/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH to activate my virtual environment previously

Comment: @johnHarbaugh as i said you have to first install that version using pyenv install 3.7.4